# CRM ServiceContext AddObjects not retrievable with LINQ in plugin

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I am currently creating some objects, setting their values and then adding them to the context, like this;

```
var address = new Customaddress();
address.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
address.CustomField = "test";

serviceContext.AddObject(address);
```

This works fine. However later in the plugin, and before SaveChanges() has been called, I am trying to retrieve a list of these created addresses, like this;

```
var addresses = serviceContext.CustomAddressSet.Where(...);
```

The resultant list of addresses contain what was there before my changes. Is there any way to subsequently query a list of added objects from the context before SaveChanges() has been called?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This doesn't work because you have, presumably, already queried to get values into the context, otherwise just skip the context and create the records using an implementation of `IOrganizationService` (instead of creating an `OrganizationServiceContext` which consumed `IOrganizationService`.)

And, to be frank, if you are trying to do this you are misuing the `OrganizationServiceContext` class: the model is **CreateContext->Query->Modify->SaveChanges->DisposeContext**.

Comment: Ok thanks.  What is happening is that I am adding objects, then passing off to some other code that copies these entities and does some other work.  It all needs to happen in the same transaction so I can't call SaveChanges() before I call it.  I will look to send the entities separately instead of in the context.